# Set PWM frequency to 25 kHz

Tags: pwm, frequency

I currently can set four PWM pins to around 31 kHz with the following code:

```cpp
void setup()
{
    TCCR1B = TCCR1B & B11111000 | B00000001; // Set PWM frequency for D9 & D10:
    pinMode(pwmPin9, OUTPUT); // Sets the pin as output
    pinMode(pwmPin10, OUTPUT); // Sets the pin as output


    TCCR2B = TCCR2B & B11111000 | B00000001; // Set PWM for D3 & D11
    pinMode(pwmPin3, OUTPUT); // Sets the pin as output
    pinMode(pwmPin11, OUTPUT); // Sets the pin as output
}
```

I found this setup somewhere, but I don't know how I can set these four PWM pins to around 25 kHz instead. How is that possible?

Comment: Do you understand how the AVR timers work?

Comment: See [my page about timers](http://www.gammon.com.au/timers).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Im not familiar and I need to set those four pins to around 25kHz at the beginning . I have hurry to finish a project and I would be glad any help. The code I have sets to 31kHz. Can I modify it to 25kHz? DC motors require that freq.

Comment: @NickGammon Thanks but I really dont have enough time to study these at the moment. Could you provide me the code part to setup 25kHz. Im lost

Comment: Why four pins? Are they all going to have different duty cycles? Why not one pin and send it to four different places?

Comment: `I currently can set four pwm pins to around 31kHz with the following code` - I just tried your code and it did not output anything.

Comment: I need to tune their exact rpm so their duty cycles will be slightly different. How about is it possible to set 2 pins only to 25kHz?

Comment: This code can be easily adapted to set the frequency to 31400, 3920, 490, 123 or 30.6 Hz. Other frequencies would not be so simple, and will most likely involve a change in the resolution of the PWM output. Can you live with a resolution of only 41 steps? Or 80 steps but loosing the “phase correct” feature? Or 321 steps but only on pins 9 and 10?

Comment: I think the last option would be great then I use two Ard. boards. Can you help me with that part? Im not familiar

Comment: While discussing with Gerben, I just thought about a fourth possibility: You could slow down the main system clock to 8 MHz and use the three timers. You would then have 4 PWM channels at 25 kHz with 161 steps on a single Arduino Uno. The cost would be loosing the timing functions (`millis()`, `delay()` and co.), having to adjust the serial baud rates, and having the whole program run half as fast. Would that be an interesting option?

Comment: @EdgarBonet Thanks for your detailed great answers. In my current code I can control 31kHz four pwm pins. At the same same time I can use LCD screen(I use delay() here to prevent flickering) and baud-rate is 9600. So if I use your 8MHz suggestion, which baudrate should I use?

Comment: With the CPU @ 8 MHz, if you `Serial.begin(19200)`, the actual baud rate will be 9600 bps. `delay()` may kind of work, but in units of 39.0625 µs.

Comment: The best material explaining PWM with the AVR timers I have found so far is the YouTube video *"[8. Arduino Timers and Counters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=faCVhp7gm-g)*" (1 h 00 m 08 s).

Comment: searched this out, it's right what I need.
How can modify it to output about 14 KHz? in fact between 11 - 19 khz OK.
Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am posting this second answer since I realized it is possible to have
4 PWM channels at 25 kHz with 161 steps on a single Arduino Uno. This
involves [changing the main clock frequency to 8 MHz](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/25591), which
has some side effects since the whole program will run half as fast. It
also involves reconfiguring the three timers, which means loosing the
Arduino timing functions (`millis()`, `micros()`, `delay()` and
`delayMicroseconds()`). If these trade-offs are acceptable, here is how
it goes:

```c++
void setup()
{
    // Set the main system clock to 8 MHz.
    noInterrupts();
    CLKPR = _BV(CLKPCE);  // enable change of the clock prescaler
    CLKPR = _BV(CLKPS0);  // divide frequency by 2
    interrupts();

    // Configure Timer 0 for phase correct PWM @ 25 kHz.
    TCCR0A = 0;           // undo the configuration done by...
    TCCR0B = 0;           // ...the Arduino core library
    TCNT0  = 0;           // reset timer
    TCCR0A = _BV(COM0B1)  // non-inverted PWM on ch. B
        | _BV(WGM00);  // mode 5: ph. correct PWM, TOP = OCR0A
    TCCR0B = _BV(WGM02)   // ditto
        | _BV(CS00);   // prescaler = 1
    OCR0A  = 160;         // TOP = 160

    // Same for Timer 1.
    TCCR1A = 0;
    TCCR1B = 0;
    TCNT1  = 0;
    TCCR1A = _BV(COM1A1)  // non-inverted PWM on ch. A
        | _BV(COM1B1)  // same on ch. B
        | _BV(WGM11);  // mode 10: ph. correct PWM, TOP = ICR1
    TCCR1B = _BV(WGM13)   // ditto
        | _BV(CS10);   // prescaler = 1
    ICR1   = 160;

    // Same for Timer 2.
    TCCR2A = 0;
    TCCR2B = 0;
    TCNT2  = 0;
    TCCR2A = _BV(COM2B1)  // non-inverted PWM on ch. B
        | _BV(WGM20);  // mode 5: ph. correct PWM, TOP = OCR2A
    TCCR2B = _BV(WGM22)   // ditto
        | _BV(CS20);   // prescaler = 1
    OCR2A  = 160;
}

void loop()
{
    analogWrite( 3,   1);  // duty cycle = 1/160
    analogWrite( 5,  53);  // ~ 1/3
    analogWrite( 9, 107);  // ~ 2/3
    analogWrite(10, 159);  // 159/160
}
```

Unlike the [other answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/25623), this does not need a modified version of
`analogWrite()`: the standard one will work fine. Only care should be
taken that:

1. The value written should be between 0 (meaning always LOW) and 160
   (always HIGH), inclusive.
2. Only pins 3, 5, 9 and 10 are available. Attempting to `analogWrite()`
   to pins 6 or 11 will not only fail to deliver a PWM output, it will
   also change the frequency on pin 5 or 3 respectively.

Comment: Been very long time and now I'm stuck with the same thing with Arduino Due which uses another processor. I would be glad if you hae any input here https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/67053/trouble-with-setting-the-pwm-frequency-for-arduino-due

Answer (score 13):

You can configure Timer 1 to cycle at 25 kHz in phase correct PWM mode, and use it's two outputs on pins 9 and 10 like so:

```c++
// PWM output @ 25 kHz, only on pins 9 and 10.
// Output value should be between 0 and 320, inclusive.
void analogWrite25k(int pin, int value)
{
    switch (pin) {
        case 9:
            OCR1A = value;
            break;
        case 10:
            OCR1B = value;
            break;
        default:
            // no other pin will work
            break;
    }
}

void setup()
{
    // Configure Timer 1 for PWM @ 25 kHz.
    TCCR1A = 0;           // undo the configuration done by...
    TCCR1B = 0;           // ...the Arduino core library
    TCNT1  = 0;           // reset timer
    TCCR1A = _BV(COM1A1)  // non-inverted PWM on ch. A
           | _BV(COM1B1)  // same on ch; B
           | _BV(WGM11);  // mode 10: ph. correct PWM, TOP = ICR1
    TCCR1B = _BV(WGM13)   // ditto
           | _BV(CS10);   // prescaler = 1
    ICR1   = 320;         // TOP = 320

    // Set the PWM pins as output.
    pinMode( 9, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    // Just an example:
    analogWrite25k( 9, 110);
    analogWrite25k(10, 210);
    for (;;) ;  // infinite loop
}
```

Writing a value of 0 with `analogWrite25k()` means the pin will be
always LOW, whereas 320 means always HIGH. The regular `analogWrite()`
should *almost* work, but it will interpret 255 the same as 320 (i.e.
always HIGH).

This code assumes an Arduino Uno or similar board (ATmega168 or 328 @
16 MHz). The method used here requires a 16-bit timer, and thus it
uses Timer 1 as it's the only one available on the Uno; that's why only
two outputs are available. The method could be adapted to other
AVR-based boards with a 16-bit timer. As Gerben noted, that timer should
have a corresponding ICRx register. There are 4 such timers on the
Arduino Mega, each with 3 outputs.

Comment: It might be useful to explain that this method only works for timer1, as the other timers don't have a `ICRx` register. At most, you can only have one PWM pin per timer, for timers 0 and 2.

Comment: @Gerben: Don't all the 16-bit timers have that register? At least on the Mega they do.

Comment: Yes, but only timer1 is 16-bit  on the ATMega328. The rest are 8-bit. And  the OP wants 4 PWM output, and your solution only provides 2. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Gerben: No, you are right. I just say that requiring ICRx seems to be redundant with requiring the timer to be 16-bits. For the Uno and Mega at least, not sure about other AVR-based Arduinos. The OP understand this only provides 2 PWM channels: see my comment on his question and his answer.

Comment: On the ATMega328 (which the OP is using) only timer1 has the `ICRx` register. For the others you'd have to use `OCRxA` as TOP, which will make it impossible to use PWM on the `OCxA` pin. The OP said he/she was okay with only two PWM pins, but then says he/she would be using 2 Arduinos. It should still be possible to do with only 1 Uno, if the OP's willing to loose `millis` and `delay`.

Comment: @Gerben: Only one Uno? Are you talking about the other two options I proposed (i.e. setting the prescalers to 8)? Oh, one could also change the frequency of the main clock and have 161 steps, I hadn't though about that one. Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: I wasn't really following the main comment thread. I was indeed talking about your 41 step alternative. (I'm not sure if the OP really needs more thatn 41 steps for RPM control.)

Comment: @Edgar Bonet
I am trying to follow this and generate the same 25khz on pin 8 of arduino mega which is controlled by TIMER 4; I dont see any success; could you please help?

Comment: @techniche: 1. Works for me. Maybe you forgot to set `COM4C1` in `TCCR4A`? 2. If that's not the problem, then read [How do I ask a good question?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), then update [your question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/44750) by including your full source code and clearly stating what you expect the program to do and what it does instead (“I dont see any success” is not considered a valid problem statement).

Comment: @EdgarBonet - thanks a lot for the response and help; I am able to generate the pwm signal and someone else verified it with an alpine 64 gt fan and it seems to work; its not working with the fan I have https://www.amazon.in/StorinTM-CPU-Cooler-Cooling-Connector/dp/B06XJV1SH8/ It is a standard CPU fan with 4 wires and its infact used a lot; could it be an issue with the fan and the pwm wire is just for show off?