# Need help to set PWM frequency to 25kHz on pin 8 of Arduino Mega

Tags: pwm

I am trying to follow [Need help to set PWM frequency to 25kHz](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/25609/need-help-to-set-pwm-frequency-to-25khz) and generate the same 25khz on pin 8 of arduino mega which is controlled by TIMER 4; I dont see any success; could someone please help?

Given below is the code I have tried based on an answer by @EdgarBonet in the linked post and  I tried on connecting fan pwm on each of the 3 pins 6, 7, 8 one by one and still cannot get the speed to change and the fan is just running at full speed;

```
void analogWrite25k(int value)
{
    OCR4A = value;
    OCR4B = value;
    OCR4C = value;
}

void setup()
{    
    TCCR4A = 0;           
    TCCR4B = 0;           
    TCCR4C = 0;           
    TCNT4  = 0;           
    TCCR4A = _BV(COM4A1)  
           | _BV(COM4B1)  
           | _BV(COM4C1)  
           | _BV(WGM11);  
    TCCR4B = _BV(WGM13)   
           | _BV(CS10);   
    TCCR4C = _BV(WGM13)   
           | _BV(CS10);   
    ICR4   = 320;         

    // Set the PWM pins as output.
    pinMode( 8, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    analogWrite25k(10);
    for (;;) ;  // infinite loop
}
```

edit2:

Thanks for the hints by @dannyf; I read the datasheet again and below is what I am trying now but even this is not working and I am really unable to figure out if something is not right in this; I am trying to set value of OCR4C only in analogWrite25k method since fan pwm line is connected to digital pin 8 of my Mega;

```
TCCR4A = 0;
TCCR4B = 0;
TCNT4  = 0;        
TCCR4A = _BV(COM4C1)  
      | _BV(WGM41);  
TCCR4B = _BV(WGM43)   
     | _BV(CS40);   
ICR4   = 320;         // TOP = 320
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65706/discussion-on-question-by-techniche-need-help-to-set-pwm-frequency-to-25khz-on-p).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a properly working answer for the question finally; Thanks to KIV's answer on [Need help to set PWM frequency to 25kHz on pin 8 of Arduino Mega to control speed of a 4-wire cpu fan](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/44809/need-help-to-set-pwm-frequency-to-25khz-on-pin-8-of-arduino-mega-to-control-spee)  an additional usful thing he has added is to allow setting of duty cycle from serial monitor input for convenience while testing;

```
void analogWrite25k(int value)
{
    OCR4C = value;
}

void setup()
{    
    TCCR4A = 0;
    TCCR4B = 0;
    TCNT4  = 0;

    // Mode 10: phase correct PWM with ICR4 as Top (= F_CPU/2/25000)
    // OC4C as Non-Inverted PWM output
    ICR4   = (F_CPU/25000)/2;
    OCR4C  = ICR4/2;                    // default: about 50:50
    TCCR4A = _BV(COM4C1) | _BV(WGM41);
    TCCR4B = _BV(WGM43) | _BV(CS40);

    Serial.begin(115200);

    // Set the PWM pin as output.
    pinMode( 8, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    int w = Serial.parseInt();
    if (w>0) {
        analogWrite25k(w);
        Serial.println(w);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

easy.

1. find a copy of the datasheet for your mcu;
2. go to the section about your timer;
3. figure out a prescaler setting that yields the maximum roll-over count;
4. pick the timer mode that supports the roll-over count;
5. write your own analogWrite() function;
6. [optional] if you wish to reuse the stock analogWrite(), make sure that roll-over count calculated in 3) is a valid data type for the stock analogWrite(). If not, increase the prescaler in 3) until it is.
7. done.

edit: i decided to give it a try.

the following code:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pwm1Set(TMR1_PS8x, F_CPU / F_PWM1 / 8);       //ps = 8x, top = F_CPU / F_PWM / 8 = 80
  analogWrite(9, 20);                           //dc = 20/80=25%
  analogWrite(10, 40);                          //dc = 40/80=50%
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

produced the following output on an ATMega328p's TIMER1.

[image]

i'm reasonably sure that the output is indeed 25Khz.

the code itself however is capable of generating pwm at other frequencies.

edit2: the same code on mega2560 generating 25Khz pwm on pin6/7/8:

[image]

code used for that is as follows:

```
  //ps = 8x, top = F_CPU / F_PWM / 8 = 80
  //DC on Pin 6 = 20/80 = 25, 
  //DC on Pin 7 = 40/80 = 50,
  //DC on Pin 8 = 60/80 = 75,
  pwm4Set(TMR4_PS8x, F_CPU / F_PWM4 / 8); analogWrite(6, 20);  analogWrite(7, 40);  analogWrite(8, 60);
```

pwm4Set() is a copy of pwm1Set(). Both are simple enough: only 5 lines of code used.

Comment: thanks for the response but the question was specific to arduino mega 2560;

Comment: @dannyf - thanks for the edit and help on mega but I am not sure where to get the pwm1Set or pwm4Set functions; are they builtin functions or part of some additional library?