# How to add prefactor to clock frequency at compile time?

Tags: arduino-mega, frequency

I want to use an Arduino Mega at 8MHz because my power supply is bad and I have only 4.3V (no way I can fix that), which is outside the operation range of the ATMega1280 at 16MHz. I think the right way to do it is to put a pre-factor 2 on CLKPR (tell me if I am wrong)? I know that several pages explain how to do so in a sketch: see [How can you reduce the clock frequency of an Arduino Mega?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/25591/how-can-you-reduce-the-clock-frequency-of-an-arduino-mega) , https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Prescaler .

However, both those methods reduce the Mega frequency at run time, by setting the CLKPR register during the setup loop or another function, mess up with the *millis()*, *delay()*, *Serial* etc, and in addition I guess this means that the Mega is running at an out-of-spec 16MHz until the prefactor is set in the setup loop (?). So my question (I searched for it but found no answer) is:

- Can one set the clock prefactor at compile time, so that:

  - the compiler knows about it,
  - the *millis()*, *delay()*, *Serial* and similar are not disturbed
  - the register is set immediately at boot (i.e. no need to change the registers in the setup)

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 and 3 can be solved by putting it in one of the [initialization sections](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/mem_sections.html). 2 can be solved by creating and using a board.txt entry with the appropriate FCPU.

```c++
#include <avr/power.h>

void __attribute__((naked, section(".init1"))) preprescale(void)
{
  clock_prescale_set(clock_div_2);
}
```

Comment: 1. avr-gcc 4.9.2 tells me “_error: attributes are not allowed on a
function-definition_”. I took the liberty to edit your code into a form
that this version of gcc accepts. 2. I would normally use `.init3` for
that, but it appears that `clock_prescale_set()` does not rely on `r1`
being zero, so `init1` is fine.

Comment: @EdgarBonet: Thank you for fixing it, it's been a while since I've had to actually do this.

Answer (score 0):

Clock speed is controlled by fuse settings and as such can be set at compile time - whether that will conflict with your bootloader is anyone's guess.

Gcc-avr allows fuse settings but you will need to burn it separately. F_CPU needs to be changed accordingly.

Comment: All the CKDIV8 fuse does though is start with the prescaler at /8 instead of /1.